# Subdomain redirect when using HTTPS

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting, redirect

My website runs on WooCommerce in public_html. I have a Subdomain in a public_html/sub. When I try to access the sub using HTTPS it seems to redirect to /wp-admin. I'm using the default URL rewrites that come with WooCommerce. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Apache Config / Vhosts etc.

Basically, search for *:443 in the configuration file (or [ipaddress]:443 if you have fixed IP addresses associated with your server).

This will explain the difference in behaviour.